# Create a cache for DNS system using B -TREES

Tags: c, algorithm, caching, dns, b-tree

I've created a D.N.S cache using B-Trees , and in every node the value I keep is the I.P , list of authorities and the TTL .
Now I want to delete from B-Tree the value which TTL expires , while continuously caching. **So what do you think is the best idea ?** I have in mind two options.
 First one (which I think is bad) is to make a function that decrease every second the TTL from nodes value(That makes a lot of tree traversal). 
The second one is to keep data from system in node beside TTL(the moment I save the record) and when I make a get from key (the key is domain name b.t.w)  I subtract the data from node from the current data , convert in seconds and if is bigger that TTL delete it. 
But I don't know is one of this is better. Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: As stated in the [help], we need a [mcve]. SO is not a training resource.

Comment: I think it is required by the detail requirement and the detail dataset. The larger the dataset would be, the second solution would be better, as far as i am concerned

Comment: @YuJing I use this for a web crawler

Comment: @joesid if this domain is very sparse (10000000 domains, every domain required one or two times), use 1, otherwise, 2. If I am not learning bt or bpt, and just wanna to have a cache for specific purpose, I will use memcached, redis or leveldb  instead of handwriting.